# check status of network printer in linux

Tags: linux, rhel, printer

I need to enable/disable print button in my application based on status of available printers.

For USB drivers, I am checking sysfs ( /sys/class/usbmisc/lp0/dev ).
But for Network drivers I didn't get such node.
So I am using lpstate -p command to get status.
If status is idle or ready, I accept it as network printer is available.

**Is there a better way of checking network printer status??**

Comment: Don't you also need to handle virtual printers such as Cups-PDF and Boomaga?

Comment: No, only physical printer.